# Accessing a property value 'nested' inside other property/variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a property value deep inside another received variable. I don't know the terminolgy so apologies but cant describe it properly which the image below.

I am using a Library called CmdMessenger, to send/recevie data over serial port.
I receive data back from the serial port using the libray, no problem. But There is some data I need to extract which is 'nested' inside the variable as shown in the Locals screenshot below.
I receive the 'arugument' variable at the top, and can read its immediate 'Arguments' property fine, but I wish to extract the data from the other highlighted 'arguments' property at the bottom of the list, which currently has 'PBC' as its value. See screenshot:

[image]

```
public static void SendFirmwareVersion(ReceivedCommand arguments)
{
    //read value ok from root of that property.
    string[] x = arguments.Arguments;
    
    //Then need to read value from other property deep inside that?
}
```

This is not soemthing i've had to do before, so quite frankly wouldnt know where to start, but it seems possible as there data is there?
PS: Feel free to edit the title that describes what I am trying to acheive.

Thanks.

Comment: arguments.Arguments[0];

Comment: @GHDevOps That doesnt work because the original property at the top of the locals list is called arguments.Arguments, so it just gets that value, not the one I need.

Comment: "Read *private field* of an object" is what you are looking for... but you really should not. I'd recommend deletion of this question and without telling anyone use reflection to dig deep into bowels of that object.

Comment: What value is in arguments array? `arguments.Arguments[0];`. Looking at the source code its looks like they should be the same values, the author made it private readonly for a reason, dont use reflection to get the value

Comment: @ZachHutchins They both have the "012" value, which is what I get from the first aruments.Argument. Why do you say dont use reflection when someone else suggedted that? not really something ive done before either. I take it its frowned upon?

Comment: @DanSewell Its mostly frowned upon for the simple reason is it is not something the author is guaranteeing will be there from version to version, its not a public facing property which if it was the author will have to maintain unless specified by breaking change since its feasible people could be using it. When removing a public anything its polite fashion to at least mark it obsolete or deprecated, but private they don't have to because TECHNICALLY you aren't supposed to know it exists (so to speak)